# How can I calculate the mean number of attempts needed for success?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

Given that

$$P(\text{First success on the }n\text{th attempt}) =\left( 1 - 0.8(1/2)^{n-1}\right) * P(\text{failure of all previous attempts})$$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$

How can I calculate the mean number of attempts needed for success?

Comment: Your expression is invalid. Do you mean success *by* the $n$th attempt?

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure how it’s invalid. Each successive attempt has a better chance of success than the most recent attempt. If success was sought, it might be achieved on the third attempt. If this process was then repeated an infinite number of times, which attempt would be expected to be the one that achieved success for the first time most of the time? That’s essentially what I’m asking.

Comment: So the probability of success on the first attempt is $0.2$.  Is the  probability of the first success being on the second attempt $0.6 (1-0.2)=0.48$? Do you want the expected number of attempts to get the first success?

Comment: I can see why my question led to confusion. I've now edited it to show that the probability of success on the nth attempt requires that all previous attempts failed. So, for example, success on the 4th attempt would require the sequence FFFS. If you add the 0.2 (S) + 0.48 (FS) + 0.256 (FFS) + 0.0576 (FFFS) + ... it does sum to 1 as expected.

Comment: Okay, hopefully my question finally makes sense now (on the third attempt!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the number of attempts needed for success. Then 
$$
\mathbb P(X\geq k)=\prod_{n=1}^{k-1}0.8(1/2)^{n-1}=0.8^{k-1}(1/2)^{0+1+\ldots+(k-2)}=0.8^{k-1}\left(\frac12\right)^{\frac{(k-2)(k-1)}{2}}
$$

The mean value of $X$ can be found as 
$$
\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X\geq k).
$$
For a proof, look at wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_and_countably_infinite_case.
Then
$$
\mathbb E[X]=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X\geq k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 0.8^{k-1}\left(\frac12\right)^{\frac{(k-2)(k-1)}{2}}
$$
Wolframalpha says that this sum [equal to 2.19073](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20(0.8%2F2%5E((k-2)%2F2))%5E(k-1),%20k%3D1..inf).

Comment: you might want to take a look at my post. There is something weird about the PMF...

Comment: Please see my question edit and comment above for clarification.

Comment: In vain you have spoiled the right condition. Now it sounds absurd. If all attempts are independent, then the probabiity of success at the $n$th attempt cannot be defined through the probabilities of previous attempts. Note also, that the words "Success on the $n$th attempt" and "First success on the $n$th attempt" define the different events. I treat the first one as "$n$th attempt is successful", and the second one as "$n$th attempt is _the first_ successfull attempt". Now you equated the probability of second event to the first one.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Now it is really weird. But prevoiusly it was absolutely correct. The probability that $n$th attempt is successfull is $P(n)=1-0.8/2^{n-1}$. First trial is successfull with probability $P(1)=0.2$. Second trial is successfull w.p. $P(2)=0.6$, third w.p. $P(3)=0.8$, then $0.9$, $0.95$, $0.975$ and so on. These _are not_ the probabilities of mutually exclusive events to sum up to 1. These are the probabilities of mutually independent events: successes in distinct trials.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I set up another question but now realise the answer was here all along – my bad for not reading your comments more carefully.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771020/how-can-i-calculate-the-mean-number-of-attempts-needed-to-achieve-the-first-succ#2771020

Comment: Do not apologize. It is good that now everything cleared up.