# How can I calculate the mean number of attempts needed to achieve the first success?

Tags: probability, statistics

The following questions are taken from the book 'Modern Engineering Mathematics' by Glyn James.

> Q.35 (p. 895)
>   The distribution of the number X of independent attempts needed to achieve the first success when the probability of success 0.2 at each attempt is given by
>
> P(X = k) = (0.2)(0.8)^(k-1)  (k = 1, 2, 3, ...)
>
> Find the mean, the median and the standard deviation for this distribution.

---

> Q. 45 (p. 896)
>
> In a problem similar to that in Question 35 the probability of success at the first attempt is 0.2 but the probability of failure at each subsequent attempt (if needed) is half that for the previous attempt. Find the mean number of attempts needed to achieve the first success.

I have attempted to interpret this question at the following page, but it appears to have led to confusion:

[How can I calculate the mean number of attempts needed for success?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2765430/how-can-i-calculate-the-mean-number-of-attempts-needed-for-success)

What is the method and answer for Question 45 please?

Comment: What formula(s) have you seen for calculating the expected value of a discrete probability distribution?

Comment: This is a *geometric distribution*.

Comment: You accepted an answer to your previous question.  How is this question different?

Comment: I've just de-selected the answer to the other question. In this question I'm quoting the source exercise question and I haven't attempted to interpret it myself.

Comment: The distribution in Q. 35 is a geometric distribution but is this the case for Q. 45?

Comment: Given how rapidly the failure probability is decreasing, I'd just do it numerically.  Perhaps there is a closed formula, but...

Comment: To stress:  this is clearly not a geometric distribution, at least not a standard example.    Such distributions are predicated on the notion of a constant success probability, but here your success probability goes to $1$ very rapidly.

Comment: Looking back at your previous posting, the problem is in your statement P(Success on the nth attempt)=$(1−0.8(1/2)^{n−1})$∗P(failure of all previous attempts).  This is the probability that the first success occurs on the $n$th attempt, not the probability of success on the $n$th attempt, and a lot of the comments discuss this.  This may be a language problem rather than a math problem.  Do you understand the distinction they're making?  If you multiply the probability you wrote down by $n$ and sum from $n=1$ to $\infty$ that's the answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have realised that the answer was in the answers to the last question all along – my mistake. If I work out the success on the nth attempt for each term manually, then multiply each term by n I get the same answer as that given in the linked post.